# Buddhist Tribunal on Human Rights and International Buddhist Ethics Committee

Tags: ethics

Friends, I was surfing online on buddhist ethics and came across International Buddhist Ethics Committee and Buddhist Tribunal of Human Rights.
https://buddhistcourt-gov.net

The tribunal is based out of Hong Kong and conducts trials on countries like Indonesia, organizations like unesco and also Individuals like Ken wilbur,  pronouncing verdicts and publishing them online in general forums

http://www.integralworld.net/visser110.html

http://www.academia.edu/30820216/Judgement_of_Case_Indonesia

http://www.academia.edu/34125176/Ethical_Judgment_on_UNESCO

The President and Judge of Buddhist Tribunal of Himan Rights is Maitreya Samyaksambuddha

https://maitriyana.in/master-maitreya-samyaksambuddha/

Has anybody heard of this tribunal?  Is it a private organization or an affiliate of a legal Buddhist body?

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste a penny on them

H.E. Master Maitreya Samyaksambuddha (https://buddhistnations-gov.net/2018/08/01/president/)

Let me break down the name for you

H.E. - His Excellency - This shows Mana or pride. No matter what Buddhist text you follow Abhidharma or Theravada, it will teach that arrogance and pride are illnesses of the mind

Maitreya - Is the reincarnation of Buddha in the current times.

Samyaksambuddha - Is someone who has attained nirvana (there is a lot more to this)

So yes the claim of being the promised Buddha goes a long way in explaining the trait of a teacher which lacks humility

Now, there is nothing wrong on calling oneself H.E. Buddha himself and presiding over a university with rate card without classrooms or any qualifications or lineage whatsoever or anything remotely close to zen or Buddhist values. Some people may choose to do business in the name of Buddha and that’s a moral wrongdoing.

But let's put attention to other things that you asked for.

International Buddhist Ethics Committee & Buddhist Tribunal on Human Rights

These 2 organizations are affiliated to the same university via United Buddhist Nations Organization (buddhistnations-gov.net) registered in 2017

Starting with the domain you can say this site has been created to falsely promote the university as a GOVERNMENT unit.

They conduct trials on individuals for reasons ranging from war crimes to un Buddha-like behavior.

The Tribunal

buddhistcourt-gov.net - A domain registered in 2017

This tribunal - uses a proton mail id and claims to be a legal body that has rights internationally to prosecute anyone it deems fit from United Nations to World Leaders to a common man

They send out notices in legal language accusing vaguely of things like waging war, fraud, and 100s of such things with a threat to malign and defame people. Which Buddhist in his right mind would do this

Just look at some of the cases online and you would see so many cases posted on educational portals and academia.

If they get offended by you, they will put a case on you :) I am doing this at the cost of being at the receiving end of one such notice

Above all, the cases are judged by Mr. H.E. himself - Now if that's not a fair trial, then what is?

So to answer your questions - As someone who has devoted her life to meditation, I can tell you don’t waste your time on this. There is no university, there are no classes and there is a massive scam of scaring people with -gov in the urls

Put that money to buy a big tub of ice cream and stare at it instead :D

Comment: I didn't understand the paragraph which starts "there is nothing wrong" and ends "that’s a moral wrongdoing" -- isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: When I'd read a bit in this site I had come to a similar negative impression myself. I think there's an non-buddhist agenda, political I assume, don't know more, am not investigative yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another page, which lists credentials and roles of "Master Maitreya Samyaksambuddha":

[Governing Council of WBA](https://maitriyana.com/2016/09/03/board-of-administration-of-wba/)

> RECTOR of Maitriyana Buddhist University since 2005, ... Master Maitreya has ... received higher Buddhist Degrees from World Association of Theravada.

The "World Association of Theravada" is described here:

[World Association of Theravada – Maitriyana Buddhist Community](https://maitriyana.com/2016/09/03/world-association-of-theravada/)

> WAT has created a project of Free Education for all the Bhikkhus of the world, offering them the possibility of advanced Buddhist studies free of any charge, like studies in Buddhist Philosophy, Buddhist Psychology, Buddhist Politics, Buddhist Law and Theravada Spirituality, due to an international covenant with Maitriyana Buddhist University.

The "Buddhist Tribunal on Human Rights", which you asked about, seems to explain its provenance on this page of its:

[Governing Council – Buddhist Tribunal on Human Rights – International Buddhist Ethics Committee](https://buddhistcourt-gov.net/2016/12/21/governing-council/)

> In Resolution No. 12 of the Steering Committee of the Seventh Buddhist Council organized by the World Association of Buddhism it is created an International Buddhist Ethics Committee which will be led by etc.

The "Seventh Buddhist Council" is described here:

[Seventh Buddhist Council – Maitriyana Buddhist Community](https://maitriyana.com/2016/09/03/seventh-buddhist-council/)

> Steering Committee of the Seventh Buddhist Council
>
> President: Master Maitreya Buddha

In summary, the Tribunal was created by the "seventh Buddhist council". The same person is or was president, both (formerly) of the council and (now) of the tribunal. The person has received "higher Buddhist Degrees" from a "World Association of Theravada", which awards degrees due to "an international covenant with Maitriyana Buddhist University" -- and this same person is rector (i.e. leader) of that university.

Apparently the [Agga Maha Pandita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agga_Maha_Pandita) title usually refers to an honorific which the Burmese government confers to distinguished Theravada monks -- but apparently not in this case, e.g. from his photograph Master Maitreya doesn't look like a Theravada monk.

The various qualifications (i.e. "certificates") from many recognised universities are possible (not impossible), for example the "certificate in Global Diplomacy from the University of London" is [described as](https://london.ac.uk/courses/global-diplomacy-diplomacy-modern-world) an online course, "5 weeks of study, 1-2 hours/week".

The bottom of the https://maitriyana.com/ home page says "© 2005-2018 MBU" so I guess it was founded in 2005, and that therefore Master Maitreya was its rector from the beginning, i.e. he founded it.

Answer (score 0):

The is only one "legal" and constitutional organisation within the Buddha-Dhamma: The Savaka Sangha of Bhikkhus of the Buddha. When this is gone, there is no more constitutional organisation. Neither before that nor after, are fake copies good but harmful, especially when mixed or even leaded by householder. It's the nature of hanging on household to act corrupt.

And as for "rights", "claiming", demanting, such has nothing to do with the liberationg Dhamma, but is based on grave wrong view:

Tribunal... politic... wordily affairs and yet not even metta and Silas...

> `They` covets the belongings of others, thinking, 'O, that what belongs to others would be mine!' He bears ill will, corrupt in the resolves of his heart: 'May these beings be `deported` or cut apart or `sized` or `sweep away`, or may they not exist at all!' `They have` wrong view, `are` warped in the way `they see` things: 'There is nothing given, nothing offered, nothing sacrificed. There is no fruit or result of good or bad actions. There is no this world, no next world, no mother, no father, no spontaneously reborn beings; no brahmans or contemplatives who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.'. [Kammaraputta](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.176.than_en.html#mind)

[Approving and honor of monks like Buddhadasa](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8357.msg13711.html#msg13711) is for the most a sign of corruption and objectives toward world and bondage rather to liberation leading refuge.

*[Note: this gift of Dhamma is not thought for any trade, stackes or exchange for wordily gains]*

Answer (score 0):

> In summary, the Tribunal was created by the "seventh Buddhist council". The same person is or was president, both (formerly) of the council and (now) of the tribunal. The person has received "higher Buddhist Degrees" from a "World Association of Theravada", which awards degrees due to "an international covenant with Maitriyana Buddhist University" -- and this same person is rector (i.e. leader) of that university.

Wow! That's vicious - to use the virtue of the Buddha's name and teachings to attempt to confuse and chastise. I've read of this organisation and Master Maitreya person's erroneous deeds on other Buddhist forums. I wonder why people would take so much trouble to create and foster confusion for mere material gain - it's obvious he stands to gain by accepting donations through each one of the many interlinked organisations. My accountant brother-in-law would have been better equipped to outline all the ways such organisations commit fraud. But hey, I'm only concerned by how badly this will affect the community at large when people who get conned relate such quacks with real teachers and genuine traditions.